# Workflow creating task for user in Outlook

Tags: workflow, outlook

Is it possible to create a task in outlook for a specific user via workflow? My Boss want to have every user informed via mail that there is a new element in a list (that works fine) and one User should have a task (even better a complete to do list) in his outlook task tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a task in a task list then  the assigned to user will have a task on outlook form them. You could just send them an email then this should be able to get the desired result.

[Tasks Integration with Exchange](http://blogs.office.com/2012/09/17/tasks-integration-with-exchange/) for SharePoint 2013

[How to sync & show SharePoint 2010 task items created by workflow in Outlook 2010](http://netizenapps.com/blog/?p=6)

Comment: So if I get it right it is just click the sync to Outlook button? We did this earlier but this doesn't seem to sync at all. Using O365 and all sources are saying it should work. Am I missing something? Thanks for the fast help

Comment: Now it works just takes a while Oo thanks for the help